# How to access the array values in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, json, uitableview

The phonenumber value is

```
(
    (
    9834677334
),
    (
    9977655456
),
    (
    9976367777
),
    (
    9654567877
),
    (
    9834777347
),
    (
    9994157837
),
    (
    9978855544
),
    (
    9873667378
)
)
```

code

```
- (void)parseContactWithContact :(CNContact* )contact { 

 NSString * firstName = contact.givenName; 
 NSLog(@"The firstName value is %@",firstName); 
 [tableData addObject:firstName]; 
 NSString * items = [[contact.phoneNumbers valueForKey:@"value"] valueForKey:@"digits"]; 
 NSLog(@"The phone value is %@",items); 
 [phonenumber addObject:items]; 
 NSString * email = [contact.emailAddresses valueForKey:@"value"]; 
 NSLog(@"The email value is %@",email);
  NSArray * addrArr = [self parseAddressWithContac:contact]; 

 }
```

I have fetch all the contact record ...I got a phone number values Mentioned above ,Here My problem is ,I don't know how to access the array values....When I tring to store it an array and populated into tableview, I got an error ,I have only able to accesss the first value ..can anyone help me how to access and populate into tableview

Comment: I have only able to accesss the first value --> you get the 0th index, show your tried code

Comment: share some code which you have tried.

Comment: - (void)parseContactWithContact :(CNContact* )contact
{
    NSString * firstName =  contact.givenName;
    NSLog(@"The firstName value is %@",firstName);
    [tableData addObject:firstName];
    NSString * items = [[contact.phoneNumbers valueForKey:@"value"] valueForKey:@"digits"];  NSLog(@"The phone value is %@",items);
    
    [phonenumber addObject:items];
    NSString * email = [contact.emailAddresses valueForKey:@"value"];
    NSLog(@"The email value is %@",email);
    NSArray * addrArr = [self parseAddressWithContac:contact];
   
}

Comment: @M.Kavitha - where you used this `phonenumber`, show some additional code

Comment: at the same time print this `NSLog(@"The phone value is %@",items); `

Comment: Hi sir ,See Line no :6 in the above method ...Finally i just print the phone number (NSMutableArray) value in NSLog,I got (
    (
    9834677334
),
    (
    9977655456
), etc..) I dont Know how to populate

Comment: what is this initially you print ***((***, but now you print as ***(((***

Comment: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";
    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
   
    cell.textLabel.text = [phonenumber objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   
    return cell;
}
  Here I tried to populate into tableview

Comment: @M.Kavitha - are you seen this what is this initially you print ***(( objects***, but now you print as ***((( objects***

Comment: @M.Kavitha - this one cellForRowAtIndexPath does not a problem , problem is here only `[phonenumber addObject:items]; `

Comment: @M.Kavitha - can you print this `NSLog(@"The phone value is %@",items); `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
NSString * items = [[contact.phoneNumbers valueForKey:@"value"] valueForKey:@"digits"]; 
NSLog(@"The phone value is %@",items); 
[phonenumber addObject:items];
```

remove the special chars `()` in phone numbers and append your string to `phonenumber` array and populate to your table

for e.g

```
NSString * items = [[contact.phoneNumbers valueForKey:@"value"] valueForKey:@"digits"]; 
NSCharacterSet *filterstr = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"1234567890"] invertedSet];
NSString *resultString = [[items componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:filterstr] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
[phonenumber addObject:items]; 
.... continue your same work ...
```

you get the phone number array as

[image]

Comment: This Code is Not Working ....*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbe80e03000'

Comment: @M.Kavitha - ha ha ha, I know, can you print this `NSLog(@"The phone value is %@",items)`

Comment: The item value is (
    9834677334
)

Comment: @M.Kavitha - if you are get the result as `( 9834677334 )`, my code surely works more than 100%

Comment: Sorry ,I doesn't work...NSString *resultString = [[items componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:filterstr] componentsJoinedByString:@""];....Here I got UIKit error

Comment: @M.Kavitha - try this `NSString *resultString = [[items[0] componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:filterstr] componentsJoinedByString:@""];`
`

Comment: @M.Kavitha - else forget NSCharset , use directly, `[phonenumber addObject:items[0]];`

Comment: Thanks for ur Suggestion [phonenumber addObject:items[0]]; is working